# Access parent controller in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

having same nested directives:

```
<div mydir="a">
  <div mydir="b">
  </div>
</div>
```

if `mydir` requires `?^mydir` it always get itself's controller.
[test_plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/am1WLAzAfio3yZws57X9?p=options)
is it possible to access parent's controller?

Comment: I think in your case the `parent controller` call has no sense. Because from your example directive has the same scope (not isolate)

Comment: When you do `require:^mydir` in the `mydir` directive you get the same directive's controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the angular documentation on jqLite, you can call controller() to retrieve the controller for any given element:

> controller(name) - retrieves the controller of the current element or its parent.
>   By default retrieves controller associated with the ngController directive.
>   If name is provided as camelCase directive name, then the controller for this
>   directive will be retrieved (e.g. 'ngModel').

Within your link function, you can retrieve the parent controller by calling controller() on the parent element and passing in the name of the directive:

```
var parentCtrl = iElement.parent().controller('mydir');
```

Comment: Great! That's the tile i was missing! ...It's some months i haven't used ng.. is that a new-release feature?

Comment: oh! the tiny drawback is that i must cycle parents up to find the controller i need, in case the nesting is deeper, yes?

Comment: i tried, it seems that `iElement.controller(..)` looks up recursively! nice!

Comment: That's great news - I couldn't recall if it did that by default

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$parent.a;
```

shall give you `a`

$scope is the scope injected by angular

$parent is a keyword reference to the parent scope from any scope in angular.

Yes this is JavaScript, and as was asked in the question, AngularJS powered Javascript

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer? what is `$scope` and `$parent`, and is that JavaScript or something else?