# trying to access parent controller of the same directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am unable to access parent directive's controller from nested one alone. However accessing parent controller works when `ngIf` is used together with nested directive. I would like to know what change is being introduced by `ngIf` to be able to access parent controller without it as well.

Directive looks like this:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.directive("some", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: ['?^some', '?^^some'],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrls) {
      attrs.$observe("some", function(someValue) {
        scope.someName = someValue;
        scope.parentCtrls = parentCtrls
        console.log(someValue + " ctrls: " + parentCtrls);
      });
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.toString = function() { return $scope.someName }
    }
  }
});
```

and code where nested elements can be of arbitrary depth:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head><!-- proper init here --></head>

  <body>
    <div some="outer">
      outer parent ctrls: {{parentCtrls.toString()}}
      <div>
        <div some="nested1">nested1 parent ctrls: {{parentCtrls.toString()}}</div>
        <div some="nested2" ng-if="true">nested2 parent ctrls: {{parentCtrls.toString()}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The effect is that `?^somoe` always resolves to self controller (which is explained eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240782/access-parent-controller-in-angular-directive)) and `?^^some` resolves to parent controller only for `nested2`. <del>It can be checked on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tP5A50R6ARYjAdxwXJ5c?p=preview) (tested on angular 1.3.15 and 1.4.7).</del> NOTE: above example is actually wrong (I'll try to update example soon) due to scope being shared by `outer` and `nested1`. Still the problem exist in some more complex case and the accepted answer correctly intercepted it.

**EDIT**

Accepted answer was enough for me to figure out desired way. Angular looks for parent directive's controller by calling `element.parent().inheritedData('$' + name + 'Controller')`. So instead of `?^^some` I can use `element.parent().inheritedData('$someController')` to access desired parent controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If angular has to compile html with nested directives it does it in three phases:

1. compile from the outer to the inner directive
2. pre-link from the outer to the inner directive
3. post-link (thats your link phase) from the inner directive to the outer one.

In the post-link phase the scopes are bound to the directives. This means "nested1" and "nested2" are bound to their scopes before "outer" is bound to its scope.

If you now use ng-if, this has a terminating effect on the compilation of this subtree and the binding of the scope is delayed until the expression is validated as truthy in a following compile cycle. In this case, "nested2" is bound to its scope after "outer" was bound.

Comment: That's short and to the point. While actually I was wondering how to be able to access parent controller anyway, your answer helped me to figure out quickly desired solution. Thanks!